# Inventory and Ordered items in magento 1.9.3.1 went blank

Tags: magento-1.9

I am using Magento 1.9.3.1, today i was trouble shooting the issue of a blank screen issue on Blog Extension ( Smartwave Blog provided with theme - aw blog). I have used the Advanced Tab in Magento Admin -> Configuration to disable some plugins i installed in the system to check if some plugins conflicts with Blog extension resulting in to white screen in blog manager options etc.

After that i have enabled those extensions i previously disabled, after this when i goto the Sales -> Orders and choose the latest order and my ordered items is showing blank.Also my Products page Inventory is also showing blank
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue was caused by some plugins installed in my website, i have disabled all the plugins installed on the site by using
editing app/etc/local.xml and setting the disable_local_modules node to true:

```
<config>
<global>
    ...
    <disable_local_modules>true</disable_local_modules>
    ...
</global>
...
</config>
```

Now i needs to find which plugins are conflicting.